# Adding Skins from Git Clone

Tags: codenameone

I have cloned the skins from Git -https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-skins.git. Now the question is which file do I select in each skin directory so that the emulator can have it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OTA directory contains most of the skin files but the skins git isn't "built" it contains sources and the build script is currently a Unix/Linux shell script.

I'm assuming you are asking this because there was an issue yesterday with the installation UI due to a site caching problem. This should be resolved now.

Comment: Hi Shai. Thanks for the reply. I am still getting the java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://codenameone.com/OTA/Skins.xml error.

Comment: Any guide on building. I am on Ubuntu so I can build the shell script. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? Other developers got the skin update thru. Just use ./build_skins.sh

Comment: Hi Shai. Just seen the update working minutes ago. Have built from the git clone on my machine too so I will use that instead. It didn't show initially even after switching to windows to check.